# A sequence such that $d(x_n,y)\to \infty$ has no limit in a metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$, and let $y ∈ X$. Show that if
$d(x_n,y)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty $
then $x_n$ has no limit in $X$.

I am in a metric spaces and topology course and am totally lost on how to answer this question. I understand the limit definition and sequence convergence definition using epsilon-delta, but am new to epsilon-delta style proofs. I understand the concept of what the question is asking, but don't know why the sequence has no limit nor how to show that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: "I haven't learned epsilon-delta" : how do you define limits then ?

Comment: What is your definition of a convergent sequence if not by epsilon delta?

Comment: Assume $x_n \to z$ for some $z \in X$. Triangle inequality gives $d(x_n,z) \ge d(x_n,y)-d(y,z)$. Hence $d(x_n,z) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Do it by contradicting the opposite: if the sequence had a limit $L$, the distance of $x_n$ to $y$ would tend to $d(L,y)$, which is contrary to the assumption it diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x_n \to x$ under $(X,d)$.

Apply the definition of continuity to $\varepsilon=1$ so that for some $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ we have

$$\forall n \ge N_1: d(x_n, x) < 1$$

Now as $d(x_n, y) \to \infty$ we have some $N_2 \in \Bbb N$ so that

$$\forall n \ge N_2: d(x_n,y) > d(x,y)+2$$

(going to infinity means we go above any preset bound).

Now for $m=\max(N_1,N_2)$ we have

$$d(x,y)+2 < d(x_m,y) \le d(x_m, x) + d(x,y) < 1 +d(x,y)$$

a clear contradiction. So $x_n \to x$ cannot hold.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a limit point (let say $x$), there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that converges to $x$. In particular $$d(x_{n_k},y)\leq d(x_{n_k},x)+d(x,y),$$ and thus, taking $k\to \infty $ yields $$d(x_{n_k},x)\to \infty ,$$
which contradict $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$.